# Spring 4.1.9 not working with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, java-8, spring-4

I am using spring 4.1.9 with jdk-8. I am using eclipse IDE.
My java 8 code with lambda expression

```
Runnable uploadSheet = () -> {
        // My code
};
```

compiles successfully but when I try to run the project, I receive following exception -

```
SEVERE: Servlet threw load() exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18607
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:223)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I change my code to following, it works

```
Runnable uploadSheet = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // My Code
    }
};
```

I can see resolved dependencies in eclipse as following

[image: resolved dependencies part- 1]

[image: resolved dependencies part - 2]

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the error, I think, You should use the latest version of `asm.jar` which supports Java 8. Reference [here](http://asm.ow2.org/history.html)

Comment: Indeed. Asm 3.1 is 10 years old, no way it could fully support java 8.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer below, I upgraded jersey version which resolved the issue. Thanks @amdg

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Jersey version from 1.8 to 1.19.4 (latest) resolved the issue.
It seems that jersey version 1.8 was having dependency on asm.jar (1.3 version) which was not compatible with Java 8 as suggested by @amdg